# Unable to access individual files from FileList when submitting multiple files using Axios in React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I am currently facing an issue while trying to upload multiple files with a description field using Axios in a React TypeScript application. When I submit an array of files, Axios appends the FileList as [object FileList], and I'm unable to access the individual files to send them as binary data.

Here is the simplified code structure I'm using:

```
export interface Attachments {
  id?: number;
  archiveid: number;
  file: Blob[] | undefined;
  attachmentDetail: AttachmentDetail[];
}

const addAttachments = (data: Attachments) => {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.attachmentDetail.length; i++) {
    const file = [data.attachmentDetail[i].files];
    formData.append(`Attachment[${i}]`, file[i]);
    formData.append(`Detail[${i}]`, data.attachmentDetail[i].attachmentDetail);
    console.log(data.attachmentDetail[i].files + " " + data.attachmentDetail[i].attachmentDetail);
  }
  formData.append('ArchiveId', data.archiveid!.toString());
  return axios.post<Attachments, any>('/AttachmentFile', formData, {
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
  });
};
```

this my agent function that i submit my attachments

```
addAttachments: (data: attachments) => {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData()
    for (let i = 0; i < data.attachmentDetail.length; i++) {
      const file=[data.attachmentDetail[i].files];
      formData.append(`Attachment[${i}]`,file[i]);
      formData.append(`Detail[${i}]`, data.attachmentDetail[i].attachmentDetail);
      console.log(data.attachmentDetail[i].files + " " + data.attachmentDetail[i].attachmentDetail);
    }
    formData.append('ArchiveId',data.archiveid!.toString());
    return axios.post<attachments, any>('/AttachmentFile', formData, {
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    });
  },
```

I have created an interface Attachments to define the structure of the file submission. However, when I submit multiple images, the files are appended to the FormData as [object FileList] instead of individual files.

I have prepared a CodeSandbox with the code to demonstrate the issue:

[codeSandbaox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-raman-4qcvej?file=/src/App.tsx)

and i expect that when i submit multiple images it should submit as `[binanry]` and now when i submit images it's submitting as `[object filelist]`.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to access the individual files from the FileList in order to submit them correctly as binary data using Axios. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution for my question.

create a array from `data.attachment[i].files`

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData()
for (let i = 0; i < data.attachmentDetail.length; i++) {
  // Create array from files
  const filess = Array.from(data.attachmentDetail[i].files);
   //loop file and append in attachment
  for (let index = 0; index < filess.length; index++) {
    formData.append('Attachment', filess[index]);
    
  }
  formData.append('Detail', data.attachmentDetail[i].attachmentDetail);
}
formData.append('ArchiveId',data.archiveid!.toString());
return axios.post<attachments, any>('/AttachmentFile', formData, {
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
});
```

so first i looped `data.attachmentdetail`
than i select files from `attachmentdetail` array store it in new file array
than i looped file array and append it to attachment That's all it worked.